# How to disable popover behaviour for an inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I have a container with some details and a button inside it. and the container has popover behavior when we hover over it. the problem is I need to disable popover behavior while hovering over the button inside it. heres the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dckmyx5r/) Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">
  <p>name: </p>
  <p>age: </p>
  <p>department:</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Connect</button>
</div>

$('.container').popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    content: "sample content"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below codes into JavaScript block.

```
$('.container button').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.container').popover('hide');
});

$('.container button').mouseout(function(e) {
    $('.container').popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('.container button').hover(function(){
    $('.container').popover('hide');
},function(){
  $('.container').popover('show');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fwcrt2hy/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest...

```
$('.container p').popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    content: "sample content"
});
```

(i.e. changing the selector to `.container p`) because the only content in your `.container` *besides* the `<button>` is paragraph (`<p>`) elements.

#### Possible Drawbacks

If your `.container` has padding, the padding area will not trigger the `popover` behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but the issue is that I'm using this in multiple places with different layouts so I need to use 'container' as the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selector` option within `popover()` method. If a selector is provided, popover objects will be delegated to the specified targets. In practice, this is used to enable dynamic HTML content to have popovers added.

```
$(function () {
    $('.container').popover({
        trigger: "hover",
        content: "sample content",
        selector: 'p'    //added this line
    })
});
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options